# mirth javascript Translation returns in error

Tags: javascript, mirth

I am using the **mirth application** to translate the HL7 Message to push into my database.

> I am using the javascript to translate

```
method see the code below.
    if (msg['PID']['PID.13']['PID.13.4'].toString() == null){
    return "no email";
}
else{
    return "email there";
    }
```

but my output is 
    id: MH002079217v003
    emailid: **${patientIdentification_phoneNumber_home1_emailAddress}**
    phoneno: 7022027430
    firstname: 002

see instead of email I am getting the variable name, the output is not returned.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing your channel I can only speculate, but I believe you are getting the variable name as your value because that variable has not been successfully set in a map.

```
if (msg['PID']['PID.13']['PID.13.4'].toString()) {
  connectorMap.put('patientIdentification_phoneNumber_home1_emailAddress', 'email');
}
```

In the example above, should the email be an empty value the body of the `if` statement would not execute. When you then use the variable in velocity, `${patientIdentification_phoneNumber_home1_emailAddress}`, if it is null the variable cannot be replaced.